# POSTGRES: Aggregating full table data in case of table partitions

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm new to table partitions in Postgres and have one doubt.
Let us assume I have a table:

```
product_visitors
```

I can create multiple partitions like:

```
product_visitors_year_2017
product_visitors_year_2018
```

etc.

I can create a trigger which can redirect insertion on product_visitors to appropriate table.

My question is, what if I want to aggregate on full data of product_visitors? For example, products and their visit count

As I understand, at the moment, data resides in year wise tables instead of main table

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 10 `inserts` will automatically be routed to the correct partition.

If you select from the "base table" `product_visitors` without any condition limiting the rows to one (or more) specific partitions, Postgres will automatically read the data from all partitions.

So

```
select count(*)
from product_visitors;
```

will count the rows in **all** partitions.